# Creating a .JAR file fails

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I'm using Eclipse, and I have a pretty simple project, I'll save you the code. It executes just fine and runs just fine. It has two .java files, in fact, the project tree is like this:

```
**mewLog**  
 - src/ (dir)   
   mewlog/ (package)  
    - MLGlobal.java  
    - MLMain.java (surprise, this one contains main and some initialization methods)    
   mlGUI/ (package)  
     - this one is empty (empty package!)
```

So, I go to File -> Export. I follow the steps as per usual and it makes my .JAR file just fine without any warnings or issues. Good!

So far so good one would say, so I rush up to my Terminal, navigate to the folder I exported my jar in, and execute it as follows:

```
java -jar mewLog_macosx-x86.jar
```

BAM! Here it goes wrong, the terminal gives me the following output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: MLMain
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MLMain
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
```

Ok. Before you say "Oh hurr durr you gotta add a class path". I tried, it doesn't work, just gives me "BLAH" no matter what I do.

I'm using Mac OS X Snow Leopard.

Output from `jar -tf mewLog_MacOSX-x86.jar`

```
jar -tf mewLog_MacOSX-x86.jar  
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF  
.project  
.classpath  
mewlog/MLGlobal.class  
mewlog/MLMain.class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

does

`java -cp mewLog_macosx-x86.jar mewlog.MLMain`

work?

if so then your manifest file in the Jar is pointing to the wrong Main-Class (Not taking the package into account)

Comment: What does "not working" look like?  This is a good example of how to not ask questions.  Read this: http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Comment: @Jesse: that's because it's wrong. It should be -cp rather than -jar when specifying the main class on the command line

Comment: It was edited, it works now, hurrah. But why? I'm not understanding why it does work now? I have seen this solution many, many times, but it never worked. Only difference is that mewlog. is added infront of it now, is that because of how packages work? I should add, this is the first time I work with packages. However, how would I write this in my manifest? mewlog.mewlog.MLMain?

Comment: That's because: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4891924/creating-a-jar-file-nothing-works-desperate-help/4892000#4892000 as per "how to add in the manifest" .. see my original answer :P

Comment: Yes but that didn't work for some reason. Anyway, I made some amendments to my manifest, and it works now. I actually understand why it works now too, big thanks to all of you. I can go back to coding in peace... :P

Comment: all classes in java need to have their full package name.. So your Main-Class attribute in the Manifest file pointed to MLMain, as opposed to it's full Name of mewlog.MLMain So when you ran it with the -jar command it looked for the Main-Class and then couldn't locate the class.  With the -cp it adds the jar into the classpath and then looks for the class specified after as the entry point, (in the case above pkgname.class). If you want it to work with the -jar option just set Main-Class: mewlog.MLMain -- see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html  for more info.

Comment: Thank you for that document, I read it through and I will never make the same mistake again. :)

Comment: @Jesse: Packages and fully qualified names can be quite confusing when you first encounter them, but once you've understood it, it rarely ever is an issue.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, .java files don't go into JAR files - .class file do.  The JVM can't execute .java files.  You have to compile them first.

Second, you have to add a manifest specifying the class that has the main method if you intend to make this an executable JAR.

Best to leave Eclipse out of it and do it by hand the first time.  Use the jar.exe tool in the /bin directory.

[Here's](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/index.html) a link that may (or may not) help you.

Comment: I already unpacked my .JAR and the files inside are .class files, there is a manifest, as I made one. I'm not new to Java, but I've never ran into this before, no matter what I do, it's not working. Thanks though.

Comment: Okay, so are the .class files showing a path that corresponds to the correct package structure?  Are you sure your manifest is correct?  Go through the link I sent you - it'll tell you precisely what you need to do.  If it still doesn't work, it means you're doing it wrong.

Comment: I'll try that, hopefully it'll help me out. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the main class needs to be listed with its fully qualified name, i.e. inclding the package. Java is looking for the class `MLMain`, which means it looks directly in the class path root. But your class is  `mewlog.MLMain`, inside the `mewlog` package.

Comment: See Doon "comment/answer/question"  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4891924/creating-a-jar-file-nothing-works-desperate-help/4891959#4891959  I think is not a fqn problem

Comment: @OscarRyz: See comment there.

Comment: This, together with the link provided by @OscarRyz solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Dumb question, but did you choose "File->Export->Java->JAR file" or "File->Export->Java->Runnable JAR file"? A jar is not by default runnable unless the Manifest.MF file tells the VM what the main class is.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put compiled class in the jar and specify in the manifest file which is the main class.

Try this in the terminal:

```
$cat Hola.java
package hola;

class Hola {
        public static void main( String ... args ) {
                System.out.println("Hola mundo!");
        }
}

$cat  m.mf
Main-Class: hola.Hola

$javac -d . Hola.java


$jar -cmf m.mf hola.jar hola

$java -jar hola.jar
Hola mundo!
```

Then compare the content of your jar and see what's different ( beside the obvious different class names )

The point here is to identify if the structure of your jar file is correct or not ( providing the output of `jar -tf mewLog_macosx-x86.jar` would help too )

I hope this helps.

Comment: Ok, progress is made, I'm now getting this: Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute from mewLog_MacOSX-x86.jar

Comment: As per your update, Doon's (corrected) answer should work. If you want to have a self running jar ( that you can invoke with `open myjar` or double click on it )  you have to create a manifest file where you specify which your `Main-Class` is ( see example above ).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest

1. creating the JAR file from command line with java -jar and familiarizing with the build process. See http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/basicsindex.html
2. installing the Fatjar plugin for Eclipse from http://fjep.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Good lord, does Eclipse really require a plug-in just to create an executable JAR?

Comment: @duffymo: no, eclipse works fine as long as your code does not depend on *other* jars. If it does, eclipse on its own repackages all classes from them into your executable jar, which is messy and could be legally questionable. Fatjar creates nested jars, which requires a special classloader and is very slow. There is no really good solution.

Comment: I was about to say, sounds a little silly to install a plug in. :P

Comment: Installing the plugin was offered as second option, if the submitter wanted it to "just work" without understanding the process.